# How to handle & differentiate both click & drag mouse button events?

Tags: keymap

Is it possible to handle both click and drag for keymaps in emacs?

- Click: Press and release with no motion.

  Activates action `A`.
- Drag: Press & move *(beyond a threshold)*.

  Activates another action `B`, which can be interactive, using the release event to finish.

Note that emacs built in drag events only activates on final release, which is different to the kind of drag I'm asking about.